# How to use Cell Address in string format with Range?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get the non-empty cell count between cell containing `Nikunj` and cell containing `Deepak`.
[image: This is data set i have]

```vb
Sub Count()
    Dim txt1 As String
    Dim txt2 As String
    txt1 = "Nikunj"
    txt2 = "Deepak"
    With Worksheets(1).Range("b1:b20")
        Set a = .Find(txt1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set b = .Find(txt2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With

    arra = Split(a.Address, "$")
    arrb = Split(b.Address, "$")
    newa = Join(arra, "")
    newb = Join(arrb, "")

    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("newa:newb")) 
End Sub
```

I have a cell address in ***xlA1*** format as string in  ***newa*** and ***newb*** which I am not able to use with `WorksheetFunchtion.CountA`.

How do I convert the address of the cell from string to a format which is accepted as range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `Range(a, b)` to `CountA` and dispense with the need to parse the cell addresses:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Count()

    Dim txt1 As String
    Dim txt2 As String
    Dim a As Range
    Dim b As Range

    txt1 = "Nikunj"
    txt2 = "Deepak"

    With Worksheets(1).Range("b1:b20")
        Set a = .Find(txt1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set b = .Find(txt2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With

    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(a, b))

End Sub
```

Comment: This is better than my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Robin Mackenzie. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

You immediate problem is that `"newa:newb"` is a string that contains actually the characters "newa:newb", not what is stored in the variables `newa` and `newb`. To concatenate string variables, use the `&` operator:

```
newa & ":" & newb
```

however, as Robin Mackenzie noted, this is not necessary

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(a, b))
```

should do the same.

---

btw, the `replace` function would be the easier way to remove characters from a string

```
newa = Replace(a.Address, "$", "")
```

---

Edit: it is recommended that you use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Thanks @arcadeprecinct. Both Solutions you suggested were of great help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the address directly:

```
Sub Count()
    Dim txt1 As String
    Dim txt2 As String
    Dim a As Range, b As Range

    txt1 = "Nikunj"
    txt2 = "Deepak"
    With Worksheets(1).Range("b1:b20")
        Set a = .Find(txt1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set b = .Find(txt2, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With

    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(a.Address & ":" & b.Address))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Answer @Gary's Student, but In actual problem i cannot hard code address. I need to get that based on cell value dynamically.

Comment: @techNikunj  In my code, the address are derived from the *FIND()*, **but Robin's approach is best !**

Answer (score 1):

Not requested, but an option without VBA:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH("Nikunj",B:B,0)&":B"&MATCH("Deepak",B:B,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. This may help me in some other application.